# What is pile foundation? Where we need of this type of foundation?

Tags: construction

I am little confused about pile foundation if anyone have knowledge about it then please give me some info.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What is the context for this question? Where are you located? Without that, we really won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Exchange. We could spend an hour writing a lengthy description of Piling Foundations or you could just do some research online.  The answers are there for you, you just have to look.

[Wikipedia](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=piling%20foundations&t=ffsb&ia=about)

[Pile Foundations](http://www.understandconstruction.com/pile-foundations.html)

[Search engine results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pilling%20foundations&t=ffsb&ia=about)

This site is for answers to specific questions and your question is really just asking for a broad overview of pile foundations. If after you have done your research and you need something clarified then you can post a **SPECIFIC** and **DETAILED** question.

Comment: This really is more of a comment than a good answer (I won't even go into "link only answers").

Answer (score 1):

There are driven piles and poured piles.

Driven Piles refer to posts (sawn lumber) and timbers (tree trunks) that are treated and then driven into the ground with large crane operated “pile drivers”.

Poured Piles refer to concrete poured into a hole (augured or drilled hole) or sonotube that is in the ground. Usually rebar is installed in the hole or sonotube first and concrete is poured around it.

Piles can be “end-bearing” or “friction”. End-bearing is used when you can easily reach solid bearing (usually less than 100’ or so) and friction is used when it’s deeper or never.

The soil is mush where I live and no matter how deep you go, it’s still mush. This is a result of silt being “washed” down from the hills over eons of time. These friction piles are driven down into this mush until the surrounding mush can support the load (building or bridge).

Piles are also used where the frost line is extra deep (Alaska, etc.) and it is not practical to pour a footing that deep.